# Why arent most of these other relative values working?

Tags: css

I'm experimenting with some other css values, which include ex, ch, cap, lh, but only ex seems to work. Why is this are the others not supported anymore or am I using them wrong?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

https://jsfiddle.net/c7ns5oy0/58/

```
  div{
    margin: 1px;
  }
  .ex{
    width: 200px;
    height:3ex;/** the ex value works!**/
    background-color: red;
  }
  .ch{
    width: 200px;
    height: 2ch; /**shouldnt it be equal to the height of 2 "0"s?**/
    background-color: red;
  }
  .cap{
      width: 200px;
      height: 3cap; /**shouldnt it be equal to the height of 3 "L"s?**/
      background-color: red;
  }
  .lh{
      line-height: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  .lh div{/***it seems to have zero height and width, shouldnt this be 50px in height and width?**/
      width: 1lh;
      height: 1lh;
      background-color: blue;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cap` and `lh` according to the Mozilla documentation are not yet supported.

[image]

As for `ch` the documentation states that the measurement is the width of a `0` instead of it's height. For you to have roughly 2x the height of a zero, you'd want to replace `2ch` to `4ch`

> Represents the width, or more precisely the advance measure, of the glyph '0' (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's font.

```
.ch{
  width: 200px;
  height: 4ch;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/koralarts/vhsLpLdq/1/

Comment: could you please send me a link to that documentation

Comment: It's the first link you posted in your question (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)